# Transitions changes in .xml does not apply

Tags: android, android-studio, transition

I am adding transitions to an app by first time, I have the following code and it is working:

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
...
```

**anim_slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="50%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

**anim_slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

However, whenever I make a change in xml files, it does not apply, I have tried to remove these xml files and recreate them, adding another code and it works, then if I make a change it does not work again.

I have also tried to synchronizate xml files, but no luck, am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Rebuilding project seems to work, but it is a bit slow

Answer (score -1):

make this like :

**anim_slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

**anim_slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood the question, any change in xml (e.g., duration) is not applied unless I rebuild project, so I can't test it quickly enough.

Comment: Even if I change the whole sliding code in xml to fade-in transition, it still will slide instead of fade in, unless I rebuild project.

Comment: Mr @McKernel i think you are new in android development?

Comment: @RishabhMahatha Yes, I am

Comment: Ok so always keep one thing is mind whenever you make any change in code either in java or in xml,to check that change you always need to run the application after the changes done.

Comment: Of course, after any change I press Mayus+F10 (Run 'app'), but it is not enough in this case, for transitions, for some reason, I have to rebuild the whole project, what takes more time.

Comment: @RishabhMahatha so this behavior is unusual, right? :/